# Laravel 4.1 - Enable debug at runtime

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.1 to write an application. For some reason I need to disable debug in all environments including production, but I need to provide a means for users to be able to enable debug mode without editing configuration files (app.php) whenever needed (that means at runtime)

Is there a way to do so? I tried to change debug settings in App::before but that does not seem to be the correct solution (exception handlers are already registered at that point)

**Update:**
In last paragraph I said

> exception handlers are already registered at that point

This comment is misleading I think. Exception handlers should be registered anyway.
The actual problem I need to solve is: How to change which displayer (plainDisplayer or debugDisplayer) to use?

This decision is made at runtime (whenever an exception actually occures) based on value of a variable ($debug) in Illuminate\Exception\Handler

Calling `app('exception')->setDebug(true)` makes exception handler to use debug displayer but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, specially if I'm going to put this code in App::before filter

Comment: We do `Config::set('app.debug', true)` in App::before based on a session value without any issues.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks. As I said in my question, I already tried this but did not get desired results. If this works for you then I should check and see if there is anything wrong with my code.

Comment: @ceejayoz Could you please provide more details? This is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: In `app/filters.php` we did `App::before(function($request) { Config::set('app.debug', Session::get('debug_mode', false)); });`

Comment: This is what I did before, but the problem is, when you set app.debug to true, when an exception is thrown what is displayed is a simple error page not a full back-trace. This is different from when you enable debugging from within configuration files

Comment: Then you've done something else weird, because we get the full backtrace just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit config settings using the [`Config`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#introduction) class. This will edit the settings for the current request in any enviroment.
With this you can set or get the debug value like so:

```
Config::set('app.debug', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you enable users to see your internal app debugging, that sounds like a security nightmare. Users would be able to force errors and potentially get sensitive information, such as API keys, database information, etc, etc.

Why not, throw/catch errors in your app, display a nice view to the user and log the actual errors somewhere away from the users view?

Comment: In fact, errors are already logged by default in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Only developers will have access to this feature and we can't use log files because developers do not have access to them

Comment: @Nima Is there any reason to not use the environment features built-in to Laravel in order to enable debugging for developers? Development / debugging shouldn't be done on the production server.

Comment: @John I know this is not a good thing to do, but the decision is not mine. And we actually won't have this feature enabled on production server. But the problem is, developers do not have access to log files on staging server

Comment: One thing you could do is set a cron on the staging server to email out the log file then empty it, so you get a periodic email of all the errors that have happened.

But really if this is for a staging server then why not just turn errors on in staging?

Comment: @Nima Right, so if you look into Laravel's environment configuration, you can enable debugging for the development / staging environments only, without having to worry about turning debuging on / off at runtime. Here, check this out: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: I wish people would quit saying there's no reason to do something instead of answering the question. Assume they have a reason for it, I do, that's why I googled it.

I have some automation programs I'd like to receive debug messages from the server, and they authenticate via methods users can't.